# Change inlet boundary condition of non-linear system

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, boundary-value-problem

This is a problem in modeling in hydraulic fracturing field. It's quite long so hopefully someone can patiently read and help me. [image: Hydraulic fracture propagation]

The equation numbers are match those of [the reference paper](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Epeirce/Adachi_Detournay_Peirce_IJRM_V47_p625_639_2010.pdf) by Adachi, Detournay and Peirce.

**Mathematical model**:

*The fracture profile $w(z)$ can be calculated explicitly for a given height $h$:*

$$ 
\begin{split}
w &=\frac{2}{E'}\left(p-\Delta \sigma \sqrt{h^2-4z^2}\right) + \frac{4 \Delta \sigma}{\pi E'} \sqrt{h^2-4z^2} \arcsin \frac{H}{h} \\ 
& \;
- z\ln\left|\frac{H\sqrt{h^2-4z^2}+2z\sqrt{h^2-H^2}}{H\sqrt{h^2-4z^2}-2z\sqrt{h^2-H^2}}\right|+\frac{H}{2}\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{h^2-4z^2}+\sqrt{h^2-H^2}}{\sqrt{h^2-4z^2}-\sqrt{h^2-H^2}}\right|
\end{split}\label{7}\tag{7}$$
where
$$
2\arcsin\frac{H}{h}-\left(1-\frac{p}{\Delta\sigma}\right)\pi=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{H}}\frac{K_{IC}}{\Delta\sigma} \sqrt{\frac{H}{h}}.\label{8}\tag{8}
$$
From \eqref{7} & \eqref{8} it follows that
$$
\overline{w}=\overline{w}(h),\quad p=p(h),\label{9}\tag{9}
$$
where:
$$
\overline w=\frac{1}{H} \int\limits_{-h/2}^{h/2} wdz,\quad \overline q=\frac{1}{H} \int\limits_{-h/2}^{h/2} qdz\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
*Poiseuille's law $q(z,t)$:*
$$
q=-\frac{w^3}{12 \mu} \frac{\partial w^3}{\partial x},\qquad-h/2<z<h/2 
\label{10}\tag{10}
$$
After integration over $h$ yields:
$$
\overline q=-\frac{\psi' w^3}{\mu} \frac{\partial w^3}{\partial x}\label{11}\tag{11}
$$
where
$\psi'$: shape factor

*Conservation law:*

$$ 
\frac{\partial \overline q}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial \overline w}{\partial t}+\frac{C'}{\sqrt{t-t_0(x)}}=0\label{12}\tag{12}
$$

where $C'=2C_l$, with $C_l\equiv$ *leak-off coefficient*

*Boundary conditions:*
At $x=l(t)$:
$$
\overline{w}(l,t)=\overline{q}(l,t)=0,\quad h(l,t)=H.\label{13}\tag{13}
$$
At the inlet:
$$
\overline{q}(0,t)=\frac{Q_0}{2H}.\label{14}\tag{14}
$$
**Scaling:**
$$
\begin{matrix}
\xi =x/l, & \zeta=z/h_*, 
\\ \tau=t/t_* , & \gamma=l/l_* ,
\\ \lambda=h/h_*, & \Pi=p/p_* ,
\\ \Psi=q/q_* ,& \overline \Psi=\overline q/q_* ,
\\ \Omega=w/w_* ,& \Omega =\overline w/w_*
\end{matrix}\label{15}\tag{15}
$$
and
$$
\begin{matrix}
l_*=\dfrac{\pi H^4 \Delta \sigma^4}{4E'^3 \mu Q_0}, &
h_*=H,\\
t_*=\dfrac{\pi^2 H^6 \Delta \sigma^5}{4 \mu E'^4 Q_0^2}, &
p _*=\Delta \sigma, \\
q=\dfrac{Q_0}{2H}, &
w=\dfrac{\pi H \Delta \sigma}{2E'}=M_0 \Delta \sigma
\end{matrix}\label{16}\tag{16}
$$
**Scaled governing system:**
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial \overline \Omega}{\partial \xi}=-\frac{\gamma \overline \Psi}{\Upsilon(\overline \Omega,\kappa) \overline {\Omega}^3}=F_1(\xi,\overline \Omega,\overline \Psi,\gamma)\label{55}\tag{55}\\
\frac{\partial \overline \Psi}{\partial \xi}=-\frac{\xi \gamma \dot{\gamma} \overline \Psi}{\Upsilon(\overline \Omega,\kappa) \overline {\Omega}^3}-\gamma \dot{\overline \Omega}-\frac{C}{\sqrt{\tau-\tau_0(\gamma \xi)}}=F_2(\xi,\overline \Omega,\overline \Psi,\gamma)\label{56}\tag{56}\\
\tau=\gamma \int_0^1 {\overline{\Omega}(\xi \tau)}d\xi+2C \gamma \int_0^1 {\sqrt{\tau-\tau_0(\gamma \xi)}}d\xi \label{57}\tag{57}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Boundary conditions at the inlet and at the leading edge:
$$
\begin{cases}
\overline{\Psi}(0,\tau)=1,\\ 
\overline{\Omega}(1,\tau)= \overline{\Psi}(1,\tau)=0
\end{cases}\label{39}\tag{39}
$$
The nonlinear governing system was derived using backward finite difference, composite Simpson law, Hermite... and then solved using Newton Jacobian (matlab codes is provided [here](https://open.library.ubc.ca/cIRcle/collections/facultyresearchandpublications/52383/items/1.0079337)

**Question**
Now I want the inlet injection rate $\overline{q}(0,t)$ changes in time so I can run simulation using the provided codes in the case of a variable rate. Originally, $\overline{q}(0,t)$ is constant so the scaled injection rate is $\overline{\Psi}(0,\tau)=1$. ***If I let it changes in time, what should be the form of the injection rate at the inlet $\overline{q}(0,t)$ and scaled injection rate $\overline{\Psi}(0,\tau)$ accordingly?***

Comment: Anyone can help me please? I really need help to solve this problem.